# Как установить плагин?

Tags: vue.js

Как установить этот плагин в проект? https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/
Обычно подключал js файлы или через cdn

Comment: Скачайте на веб сайте https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html. Есть две версии.

Comment: На странице нужного тебе плагина указана npm команда для загрузки `npm install -S vue-carousel-3d`